# Integrating two database queries using PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do two things here, the first is working correctly (it is copying data from one table to another). The second part however is not... This part should add the value 1 to the column "scores" but only to the latest result (which is defined by sorting "date_played"), at the moment all i am doing is adding a new result to the table..

many thanks.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// open DB connection
require_once("DbConnect.php");

// fetch now playing song and copy ratings table
$result = $db->query(
    "INSERT INTO rating(`artist`, `title`, `label`, `albumyear`, 
                        `date_played`, `duration`, `picture`, 
                        `filename`, `songid`)" .
     "SELECT `artist`, `title`, `label`, `albumyear`, `date_played`, 
             `duration`, `picture`, `filename`, `songid` " .
     "FROM historylist  
      ORDER BY `date_played` DESC 
      LIMIT 1 ");


$score  = $db->query(
    "INSERT INTO rating (`score`)".
    "VALUES ('1')".
    "ORDER BY `date_played` DESC LIMIT 1 ");

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear what you want to be different about the functionality of the script than what it is doing already. Will you please clarify.

Comment: I am pretty sure that code wont actually run anyway, so what are you actually asking

Comment: Its your code that does not make any sense. It only works, _if it works_ because you only have one row in your `historylist` table. Once you have more than one row in there you will have a complete disaster as it wont know which row to select.

Comment: Do you have a unique key in your `rating` table?

Comment: @ColinSchoen The primary key is "ID" which incriments everytime a n entry is added

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE rating set `score`=`score`+1 ORDER BY `date_played` DESC LIMIT 1
```

***EDIT***

A better way to approach this would be to get the last inserted id and use that to target the row

```
$last_id = $db->insert_id; // assuming mysqli API

$db->query("UPDATE rating SET `score` = `score` + 1 WHERE ID=$last_id");
```

Comment: When did `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` become valid syntax in an `UPDATE` query??? And where is the `WHERE` clause. Think before you answer.

Comment: Ouch, yes please do not use this answer.

Comment: I just tested this, and works perfectly on my local MAMP installation (mysql 5.5.9). Whether it solves the op's problem is a different matter!

Comment: Try it with 2 or more rows. They will all get updated. Great idea, but I doubt its what the questioner intended.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, FWIW, ORDER BY and LIMIT are not part of UPDATE in standard SQL, but they are supported in MySQL. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for that, it may take me a couple of year to find a use for that knowledge, but as the saying goes, knowledge is power.